# Android WebView PostUrl UTF-8

Tags: android, webview

In previous versions of Android this was working (need to post utf-8 params):

```
postData = "action=login&User=عربى&password=1@#(u)&^%$";
webview.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "UTF-8"));
```

But in Android 5 and 6 they removed apache package and EncodingUtils.getBytes not available by default, I do not want to manually load it.

How to natively encode the postData into utf-8 then convert it to bytes to
the webview.postUrl, tried something like this but did not work:

```
    final Charset UTF8_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    try {
        postData = URLEncoder.encode(postData, "utf-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    browser.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET));
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the definition of `EncodingUtils.getBytes` shows that it just calls `getBytes` function of `String`.

So even if you don't have `EncodingUtils.getBytes` you can call `getBytes` on `String` like this:

```
webview.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes( "UTF-8"));
```

or you can just make a copy of the original `EncodingUtils.getBytes` function :

```
public static byte[] getBytes(final String data, final String charset) {


        if (data == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("data may not be null");
        } 


        if (charset == null || charset.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("charset may not be null or empty");
        } 


        try { 
            return data.getBytes(charset);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return data.getBytes();
        } 
    }
```

https://github.com/android/platform_external_apache-http/blob/master/src/org/apache/http/util/EncodingUtils.java

Comment: postData.getBytes( "UTF-8")  will not encode the post data, it just returns utf-8 ocets as I think, I need the postData to url encoded first in utf8 then converted to bytes for postUrl method.

Comment: I just posted the alternative way of calling deprecated function you posted above. You can try if it works for you or not.